# Recursion over a Swift Sliceable

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I feel that I must be missing something obvious. Decomposing a list into the head and tail and then recursing over the tail is a standard functional programming technique, yet I'm struggling to do this for `Sliceable` types in Swift.

I have a recursive function that follows this pattern:

```
func recurseArray(arr: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    guard let first = arr.first else {
        return []
    }

    let rest = recurseArray(Array(dropFirst(arr)))
    let next = rest.first ?? 0

    return [first + next] + rest

}
```

Obviously the real code does a lot more than add each number to the next.

Note the call to `Array(dropFirst(seq))`. Converting to an Array is required since `dropFirst` actually returns an `ArraySlice`, and an `ArraySlice` isn't a  `Sliceable`, so I can't pass it to my function.

I'm not sure what sort of optimization the compiler is capable of here, but it seems to me that creating a new array from a `SubSlice` unnecessarily won't be optimal. Is there a solution to this?

Furthermore, what I'd *really* like to do is create a version of this function that can take *any* `Sliceable` type:

```
func recurseSeq<T: Sliceable where T.Generator.Element == Int>(list: T) -> [Int] {

    guard let first = list.first else {
        return []
    }

    let rest = recurseSeq(dropFirst(list)) // <- Error - cannot invoke with argument type T.SubSlice
    let next = rest.first ?? 0

    return [first + next] + rest
}
```

This time I don't have a solution to the fact that I have a `SubSlice`. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there **is** a generic solution. You need to add these generic requirements:

```
<  
  S : Sliceable where S.SubSlice : Sliceable,  
  S.SubSlice.Generator.Element == S.Generator.Element,  
  S.SubSlice.SubSlice == S.SubSlice  
  >
```

For the question posted, this gives:

```
func recurseSeq<
    S : Sliceable where S.SubSlice : Sliceable,
    S.SubSlice.Generator.Element == Int,
    S.SubSlice.SubSlice == S.SubSlice,
    S.Generator.Element == Int
    >(list: S) -> [Int] {

    guard let first = list.first else {
        return []
    }

    let rest = recurseSeq(dropFirst(list))
    let next = rest.first ?? 0

    return [first + next] + rest
}
```

Here's a useful generic reduce on any sliceable:

```
extension Sliceable where  
  SubSlice : Sliceable,  
  SubSlice.Generator.Element == Generator.Element,  
  SubSlice.SubSlice == SubSlice {  

  func recReduce(combine: (Generator.Element, Generator.Element) -> Generator.Element) -> Generator.Element? {  

    return self.first.map {  
      head in  
      dropFirst(self)  
        .recReduce(combine)  
        .map {combine(head, $0)}  
        ?? head  
    }  
  }  
}  
[1, 2, 3].recReduce(+) // 6
```

I can't take credit for this, the solution was [posted](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5914) on the Apple Development Forums.

It's a shame that the generic requirements are so involved for such a a basic operation - it's hardly intuitive! But I'm glad to have a solution...

Comment: So I was at least partially on the right track :) - Could you add a link to the devoper forum posting?

Comment: OK, but since you have to be a developer, I'm not sure if that's useful to the general audience.

Comment: I assume that many of the people which are active in the [swift] tag have a Apple developer account.

Comment: Thanks! – Actually I can *read* that posting without having to log in. Perhaps the rules changed for the "new" developer forum.

Comment: Your answer is very useful (and I just linked to this thread from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074624/recursively-parse-a-collectiontype). Unfortunately, the code does not compile anymore with the current Xcode 7.1.1, would you mind to update it?

Answer (score 3):

Actually `ArraySlice` *is* `Sliceable`, so you can recurse on 
`ArraySlice<Int>`:

```
func recurseArray(arr: ArraySlice<Int>) -> [Int] {

    guard let first = arr.first else {
        return []
    }

    let rest = recurseArray(dropFirst(arr))
    let next = rest.first ?? 0

    return [first + next] + rest
}
```

with a wrapper function which is called only once at the top level:

```
func recurseArray(arr: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    return recurseArray(arr[arr.startIndex ..< arr.endIndex])
}
```

---

I don't have a solution for your second more general problem.
The API docs for `Sliceable` state that `SubSlice` *should* be 
`Sliceable` itself (which is the case for all known `Sliceable`
types).

I have therefore the feeling that it should be possible by requesting
that `T.SubSlice` is itself sliceable with the identical `SubSlice`
type, however this does not compile:

```
func recurseSeq<T: Sliceable where T.Generator.Element == Int,
    T.SubSlice : Sliceable,
    T.SubSlice.SubSlice == T.SubSlice>(list: T.SubSlice) -> [Int] {

        guard let first = list.first else {
            return []
        }
        let rest = recurseSeq(dropFirst(list) as T.SubSlice)
        // error: cannot invoke 'recurseSeq' with an argument list of type '(T.SubSlice)'

        let next = rest.first ?? 0

        return [first + next] + rest
}
```

The compiler accepts that `dropFirst(list)` can be cast to `T.SubSlice`,
but refuses to call `recurseSeq()` on that value, which I do not
understand.

---

Alternatively, you can recurse on a `GeneratorType`:

```
func recurseGen<G: GeneratorType where G.Element == Int>(inout gen: G) -> [Int] {

    guard let first = gen.next() else {
        return []
    }
    let rest = recurseGen(&gen)
    let next = rest.first ?? 0
    return [first + next] + rest
}
```

with a wrapper that takes a `SequenceType`:

```
func recurseSeq<T: SequenceType where T.Generator.Element == Int>(list: T) -> [Int] {
    var gen = list.generate()
    return recurseGen(&gen)
}
```

Arrays and array slices all conform to `SequenceType`, so that should
work in all your cases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error regarding ArraySlice. Nevertheless, the wrapper solution feel icky from an FP point of view. Is there a way to handle this with just one function? Of course the real thrust of my question is the 2nd half - it seems incredible that this can't be done. I don't yet know what I'm going to pass to my function (an Array, Sequence etc.), so I want to make this work for all cases.

Comment: @tarmes: I have added another possible solution. It might still not be exactly what you are looking for, but that's what I could figure out.

Comment: It's a cunning solution. I'd considered using a generator but I hadn't thought of passing it as an inout to allow it to work properly. My only slight niggle is that from an FP point of view we haven't avoided mutable state (although it is localised). I'll mark this as a solution if no-one else manages to find a more readable solution (since this still feels very heavy for what should be a basic recursive operation).

Answer (score 0):

Creating an array in every iteration doesn't seem like a good idea. I don't know if the compiler optimizes it somehow, but you could probably find a different solution.

For example, in this case, you could drop de recursion and use a `for` loop instead that modifies the array in place.

```
func recurseArray2(var a: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    for var i = a.count-1; i > 0; i-- {
        a[i-1] += a[i]
    }
    return a
}
```

Comment: Actually I have to recurse, the operation that I perform is far more complicated than the simplified example I posted. Besides, performing recursion on the tail of a list is a standard function-programming technique, I feel like I must be missing something.