# Unify Arrays and Array Slices in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I'm very new to Swift, and to Apple programming in general.  I wrote this code to do a binary search.

```
func binarySearch<X:Comparable> (needle:X, haystack:[X])->X? {
    if haystack.isEmpty { return nil }
    let mid = haystack.count / 2
    let found = haystack[mid]
    if found == needle {
        return needle
    }
    else if found < needle {
        return binarySearch(needle, haystack[0..<mid])
    }
    else {
        return binarySearch(needle, haystack[mid+1..<haystack.count])
    }
}
```

and I got syntax errors on the recursive calls because the second parameter is of type `ArraySlice<X>` instead of `Array<X>`.

I dealt with this by overloading binarySearch with a version that is identical except that the second parameter is of type `ArraySlice<X>`.

I think it would be more elegant if it could all be done in one function.  Is there a suitable type that unifies both Array and ArraySlice?  I tried using `ArrayLiteralConvertible<X>` but for some reason that doesn't have a count member.  I still have a bit of trouble finding my way around in the docs, so I may easily have overlooked a better choice.

Can you suggest a good way to do this?  If it involves using a built-in class, can you perhaps give me a tip on how to find it for myself next time, instead of writing to SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the Array/ArraySlice thing is annoying. The basic generic requirements you need are detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915114/recursion-over-a-swift-sliceable) question. To get your requirements, though, unfortunately you've got to get some pretty hideous function signatures. It *is* possible, though:

```
func bSearch<
  S : Sliceable where S.SubSlice : Sliceable,
  S.SubSlice.Generator.Element == S.Generator.Element,
  S.SubSlice.SubSlice == S.SubSlice,
  S.Generator.Element : Comparable,
  S.Index : IntegerArithmeticType,
  S.Index : IntegerLiteralConvertible,
  S.SubSlice.Index == S.Index
  >(el: S.Generator.Element, list: S) -> S.Generator.Element? {

    if list.isEmpty { return nil }

    let midInd = list.endIndex / 2

    let midEl: S.Generator.Element = list[midInd] // type inference giving me some bugs here

    if midEl == el {
      return el
    }

    return midEl < el ?
      bSearch(el, list: list[midInd+1..<list.endIndex]) :
      bSearch(el, list: list[0..<midInd])
}
```

And for Swift 1.2, just swap out the body for this:

```
if isEmpty(list) { return nil }

let midInd = list.endIndex / 2

let midEl: S.Generator.Element = list[midInd] // type inference giving me some bugs here

if midEl == el {
  return el
}

return midEl < el ?
  bSearch(el, list[midInd+1..<list.endIndex]) :
  bSearch(el, list[0..<midInd])
```

Comment: Nice! – Perhaps add the information that this is Swift 2.0 and requires Xcode 7 beta.

Comment: Oops. You're dead right. I'll add it there (and I might begin to *attempt* to add a Swift 1.2 version...)

Comment: Actually I don't like using switch/case here (with an artificial default case to make the compiler happy) instead of a simple if/else if/else. But that is a matter of taste :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I originally had it in there because of compiler tantrums - couldn't manage the if statements for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this.  I agree that it's hideous.  I'll stick with my original approach, but I do intend to work through the type specification.

Answer (score 3):

To get around your initial problem, call the `Array` constructor with your slice to get an array:

```
func binarySearch<X:Comparable> (needle:X, haystack:[X])->X? {
    if haystack.isEmpty { return nil }
    let mid = haystack.count / 2
    let found = haystack[mid]
    if found == needle {
        return needle
    }
    else if needle < found {
        return binarySearch(needle, Array(haystack[0..<mid]))
    }
    else {
        return binarySearch(needle, Array(haystack[mid+1..<haystack.count]))
    }
}
```

Also, your condition should be `if needle < found`.

Comment: But then you loose the advantage of array slices, which are just references into the original array. (It would be interesting to know how smart the runtime is and how much data is copied if you create a new array from a slice.)

Comment: True. I guess we'll find out when open source Swift is released.