# Recursively parse a CollectionType

Tags: swift, generics, recursion, types

I'm writing a recursive descent parser.  I'd like my parser to work on any (or at least "many") Collections of `UInt8` (e.g., not only Swift.Array)

```
func unpack<T: CollectionType where T.Generator.Element == UInt8>(t: T) {
    let m = t.dropFirst()
    //[do actual parsing here]
    unpack(m)
}
```

However:

```
error: cannot invoke 'unpack' with an argument list of type '(T.SubSequence)'
note: expected an argument list of type '(T)'
```

This is puzzling because:

1. `dropFirst` returns `Self.SubSequence`
2. `CollectionType.SubSequence` is `SubSequence : Indexable, SequenceType = Slice<Self>`
3. `Slice` is `CollectionType`.
4. Therefore, `m` should be `CollectionType`.

However for some reason, this doesn't work.  How do I define `unpack` so it can be recursively passed subsequences?

Comment: Compare [Recursion over a Swift Sliceable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915114/recursion-over-a-swift-sliceable) for an almost identical problem.

Comment: Actually it is the *same* problem, because `Sliceable` has been renamed to `CollectionType` now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `CollectionType` in Swift anymore. Both `Array` and `ArraySlice` adopt [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence). And the `dropFirst()` method which you use is declared in `Sequence`. So you can make recursive generic function like this:

```
func unpack<T: Sequence>(t: T) where T.Element == UInt8 {
    let m = t.dropFirst()
    //[do actual parsing here]
    unpack(m)
}
```